# How do I set the length of my longtable to the textwidth?

Tags: longtable, textwidth

I have tried setting the width of my longtable with several things, but nothing seems to work. It is still exceeding my page... Can someone please help me?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{20AC}{\texteuro}

\def\setcitestyle{}
\def\citep{\cite}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\setlength\LTleft{0pt} % see p. 7 of longtable package user guide
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\begin{longtable}{@{} l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} ccc @{}}

\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Maatregel}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Onderhoudswerkzaamheden}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Jaarlijkse kosten}} \\ \hline
\textbf{Bovengronds} &  &  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Vergoenen tuinen (particulier)} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{x} & nvt \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Openbaar groen aanleggen of groen verlagen \\ (infiltratieveld)\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}- Grasmaaien (1x per 2 weken)\\ - Beluchten en verticuteren \\ (1x per jaar)\end{tabular}} & €2,15 per m2 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{WADI's} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Groendonderhoud:\\ - Grasmaaien, zwerfvuil verwijderen \\ (1x per 2 weken)\\ - Bladeren verwijderen en verticuteren \\ (1x per jaar)\\ \\ Correctief onderhoud:\\ - Opnieuw inzaaien (1x per jaar)\\ - Bodemverbetering (1x per 2 jaar)\\ - Toplaag vervangen (1x per 10 jaar)\end{tabular}} & €7,40 per m2 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Oppervlakte water aanleggen} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Klein onderhoud:\\ - Maaien natte profiel incl. verwijderen \\ drijfvuil (1x per halfjaar)\\ \\ \\ Groot onderhoud:\\ - Baggeren profiel (1x per 5 jaar)\\ - Verwijderen gezonken voorwerpen \\ (1x per jaar)\\ - Oeveronderhoud (1x per jaar)\\\setcitestyle{authoryear,square,aysep={},yysep={;}}\citep{bodemrichtlijn, regelgeving}\end{tabular}} & €2,75 per m2 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Herinrichting straat \\ (waterinfiltrerende verharding)\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Onderzoek:\\ - Visueel inspecteren (1x per jaar)\\ - Doorlatendheid meten (1x per 3 jaar)\\ \\ Onderhoud:\\ - Vegen (1-6x per jaar)\\ - Diepreiniging (1x per 1-7 jaar)\\ - Aanvullen voegspit na reiniging \\ (1x per 1-7 jaar)\\ - Onkruidbestrijding (4-8x per jaar)\end{tabular}} & €3,55 per m2 \\ \hline
\textbf{Benedengronds} &  &  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Riolering vergroten} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{x} & nvt \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Infiltratiebuizen} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Doorspuiten (1x per 3-5 jaar)} & €0,05 per m \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Infiltratiekelders} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Reiniging (1x per 5 jaar)} & €400,- per 100 m3 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Infiltratiekratten} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}- Inspectie (1x per jaar)\\ - Leegzuigen en onderhouden \\ (1x per 2 jaar)\end{tabular}} & €4,40 per m2 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Bergbezinkbassin} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Spoelpompen reinigen bergings-\\ kelder automatisch (getal ontbreekt)\end{tabular}} & nvt \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably you're interested in `xltabular` instead of `longtable`.

Comment: Welcome. When you post some code here, select it and press ctrl+k to format it.

Comment: Please make your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages. If you use `geometry`, please include these settings as well.

Comment: I made your example usable (this time) . Note that the code you copied from the manual is adding _stretch_ space to pad out the table separating the columns to make the table full width. Your table is already much too wide so changing the column separation will not help, you must format the columns eg using `p{3cm}` instead of `l`

Comment: Your table seems to be generated with some sort of table generator. Consequently your code is filled with a lot of redundant `\multicolumn` statements (that will also affect the alignment and column widths). You might want to start by removing them first.

Comment: Is your table longer than one page? This is not obvious from the example shown.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of `booktabs` for the horizontal lines, `xltabular` in order to make the table fit into the textwidth, `makecell` for the column headers and `enumitem` for the itemize lists, you can achieve the following result. I have concentrated on the first half of the table, the rest can be adapted using the same techniques:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{20AC}{\texteuro}


\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabitem}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[tabitem]{wide=0pt, nosep, leftmargin= * ,label=\textendash,}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document}

\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2.75cm}Xl}
\toprule
\thead{Maatregel} & \thead{Onderhoudswerkzaamheden} & \thead{Jaarlijkse\\ kosten} \\ \hline
\textbf{Bovengronds} &  &  \\ 
\midrule
Vergoenen tuinen (particulier) & x & nvt \\ \addlinespace
Openbaar groen aanleggen of groen verlagen \newline (infiltratieveld) 
    & \begin{tabitem}[before=\vspace{-\baselineskip}, after=\vspace{-\baselineskip}]
        \item Grasmaaien (1x per 2 weken)
        \item Beluchten en verticuteren (1x per jaar) 
       \end{tabitem}
        & €2,15 per m2 \\ \addlinespace
WADI's 
    & Groendonderhoud: \begin{tabitem}
                        \item Grasmaaien, zwerfvuil verwijderen (1x per 2 weken)
                        \item Bladeren verwijderen en verticuteren (1x per jaar)
                        \end{tabitem}
       Correctief onderhoud:\begin{tabitem}[after=\vspace{-\baselineskip}]
                              \item Opnieuw inzaaien (1x per jaar)
                              \item Bodemverbetering (1x per 2 jaar)
                              \item Toplaag vervangen (1x per 10 jaar) 
                            \end{tabitem}
        & €7,40 per m2 \\  \addlinespace
%\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Oppervlakte water aanleggen} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Klein onderhoud:\\ - Maaien natte profiel incl. verwijderen \\ drijfvuil (1x per halfjaar)\\ \\ \\ Groot onderhoud:\\ - Baggeren profiel (1x per 5 jaar)\\ - Verwijderen gezonken voorwerpen \\ (1x per jaar)\\ - Oeveronderhoud (1x per jaar)\\\setcitestyle{authoryear,square,aysep={},yysep={;}}\citep{bodemrichtlijn, regelgeving}\end{tabular}} & €2,75 per m2 \\ \hline
%\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Herinrichting straat \\ (waterinfiltrerende verharding)\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Onderzoek:\\ - Visueel inspecteren (1x per jaar)\\ - Doorlatendheid meten (1x per 3 jaar)\\ \\ Onderhoud:\\ - Vegen (1-6x per jaar)\\ - Diepreiniging (1x per 1-7 jaar)\\ - Aanvullen voegspit na reiniging \\ (1x per 1-7 jaar)\\ - Onkruidbestrijding (4-8x per jaar)\end{tabular}} & €3,55 per m2 \\ \hline
%\textbf{Benedengronds} &  &  \\ \hline
%\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Riolering vergroten} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{x} & nvt \\ \hline
%\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Infiltratiebuizen} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Doorspuiten (1x per 3-5 jaar)} & €0,05 per m \\ \hline
%\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Infiltratiekelders} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Reiniging (1x per 5 jaar)} & €400,- per 100 m3 \\ \hline
%\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Infiltratiekratten} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}- Inspectie (1x per jaar)\\ - Leegzuigen en onderhouden \\ (1x per 2 jaar)\end{tabular}} & €4,40 per m2 \\ \hline
%\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Bergbezinkbassin} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Spoelpompen reinigen bergings-\\ kelder automatisch (getal ontbreekt)\end{tabular}} & nvt \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your MWE using longtable, with all the ugly vertical and horizontal lines in place. I redefined `\arraystretch` and increased `\extrarowheight` to create more white space in the tabular.

As you will see, I calculate the column width relative to the margin and relative to the other column in the definition of the three columns:

```
    \newcolumntype{F}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}
     p{\dimexpr(((\linewidth/18)*6)-(2\tabcolsep+2\arrayrulewidth))\relax}}
```

If you prefer a different distribution, just change the figure `6` to something else, but ensure that the three definitions accumulate to 18. If you change margins, the longtable will adapt.

Inside the cells, I prefer to enclose the itemize-lists i a `\minipage` to cancel space abowe and below. The `\hsize` picks up the column width (thank you David Carlisle).

[image]

```
\documentclass[dutch]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp, array, ragged2e, enumitem}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{20AC}{\texteuro}

\def\setcitestyle{}
\def\citep{\cite}
\usepackage{longtable}
\def\arraystretch{1.1}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}

\newcolumntype{F}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr(((\linewidth/18)*6)-(2\tabcolsep+2\arrayrulewidth))\relax}}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr(((\linewidth/18)*8)-(2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth))\relax}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr(((\linewidth/18)*4)-(2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth))\relax}}


\begin{document}

\setlist[itemize]{wide=0pt, nosep, leftmargin= * ,label=\textendash}

\setlength\LTleft{0pt} % see p. 7 of longtable package user guide
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\begin{longtable}{|F|M|L|}

\hline
\endfirsthead

\hline
\endhead

\multicolumn{1}{|F|}{\bfseries Maatregel} & \multicolumn{1}{M|}{\bfseries Onderhoudswerkzaamheden} & \multicolumn{1}{L|}{\bfseries Jaarlijkse kosten} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\bfseries Bovengronds}  \\ \hline
Vergoenen tuinen (particulier) & x & nvt \\ \hline
Openbaar groen aanleggen of groen verlagen (infiltratieveld) &
\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}
\begin{itemize}
\item Grasmaaien (1x per 2 weken)
\item Beluchten en verticuteren  (1x per jaar)
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
 & €2,15 per m2 \\ \hline
WADI's &
\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}
Groendonderhoud: 
\begin{itemize}
\item Grasmaaien, zwerfvuil verwijderen  (1x per 2 weken)
\item Bladeren verwijderen en verticuteren  (1x per jaar)
\end{itemize}
\smallskip
Correctief onderhoud:
\begin{itemize}
\item Opnieuw inzaaien (1x per jaar)
\item Bodemverbetering (1x per 2 jaar)
\item Toplaag vervangen (1x per 10 jaar)
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage} & 
€7,40 per m2 \\ \hline
Oppervlakte water aanleggen &
\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}
Klein onderhoud: 
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Maaien natte profiel incl. verwijderen  drijfvuil (1x per halfjaar) 
    \end{itemize}
\smallskip
Groot onderhoud: 
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Baggeren profiel (1x per 5 jaar)
    \item Verwijderen gezonken voorwerpen  (1x per jaar)
    \item Oeveronderhoud (1x per jaar)
    \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
%\setcitestyle{authoryear,square,aysep={},yysep={;}}\citep{bodemrichtlijn, regelgeving} 
& €2,75 per m2 \\ \hline
Herinrichting straat  (waterinfiltrerende verharding) & 
\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}
Onderzoek:
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Visueel inspecteren (1x per jaar)
    \item Doorlatendheid meten (1x per 3 jaar)
    \end{itemize}
\smallskip
Onderhoud:
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Vegen (1-6x per jaar)
    \item Diepreiniging (1x per 1-7 jaar)
    \item Aanvullen voegspit na reiniging  (1x per 1-7 jaar)
    \item Onkruidbestrijding (4-8x per jaar)
    \end{itemize} 
\end{minipage} & 
€3,55 per m2 \\ \hline\pagebreak[3]
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\bfseries Benedengronds}   \\ \nopagebreak\hline
Riolering vergroten & x & nvt \\ \hline
Infiltratiebuizen & Doorspuiten (1x per 3-5 jaar) & €0,05 per m \\ \hline
Infiltratiekelders & Reiniging (1x per 5 jaar) & €400,- per 100 m3 \\ \hline
Infiltratiekratten &
\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}
\begin{itemize}
\item Inspectie (1x per jaar)
\item Leegzuigen en onderhouden  (1x per 2 jaar)
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage} & 
€4,40 per m2 \\ \hline
Bergbezinkbassin & Spoelpompen reinigen bergingskelder automatisch (getal ontbreekt) & nvt \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

One more example: with `xltabular` and defined second columns with `\minipage`:

```
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\minipage[t]{\hsize}\raggedright\arraybackslash}X<{\endminipage}}
```

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{20AC}{\texteuro}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, xltabular}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\minipage[t]{\hsize}\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}<{\endminipage}}  
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabitem}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[tabitem]{nosep, leftmargin=*, label=\textendash,}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\begin{document}

\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{}>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{30mm} R l @{}}
     \toprule
\thead{Maatregel} 
    &   \thead{Onderhoudswerkzaamheden} 
        &   \thead{Jaarlijkse\\ kosten}     \\ 
    \midrule
\endhead
%
\textbf{Bovengronds} &  &  \\
    \midrule
Vergoenen tuinen (particulier) & x & nvt \\ 
    \addlinespace[9pt]
Openbaar groen aanleggen of groen verlagen (infiltratieveld)
    & \begin{tabitem}
        \item Grasmaaien (1x per 2 weken)
        \item Beluchten en verticuteren (1x per jaar)
       \end{tabitem}            & €2,15 per m2  \\ 
    \addlinespace[9pt]
WADI's
    &   Groendonderhoud:      
            \begin{tabitem}
        \item Grasmaaien, zwerfvuil verwijderen (1x per 2 weken)
        \item Bladeren verwijderen en verticuteren (1x per jaar)
            \end{tabitem}
       Correctief onderhoud:
            \begin{tabitem}
        \item Opnieuw inzaaien (1x per jaar)
        \item Bodemverbetering (1x per 2 jaar)
        \item Toplaag vervangen (1x per 10 jaar)
            \end{tabitem}       &   €7,40 per m2        \\
    \addlinespace[9pt]
Oppervlakte water aanleggen
    &   Klein onderhoud:
        \begin{tabitem}
    \item   Maaien natte profiel incl. verwijderen drijfvuil (1x per halfjaar)
        \end{tabitem}
        Groot onderhoud:
            \begin{tabitem}
    \item   Baggeren profiel (1x per 5 jaar)
    \item   Verwijderen gezonken voorwerpen (1x per jaar) 
    \item   Oeveronderhoud (1x per jaar) \cite{bodemrichtlijn, regelgeving}
            \end{tabitem}       & €2,75 per m2      \\ 
    \addlinespace[9pt]
Herinrichting straat (waterinfiltrerende verharding)
    &   Onderzoek:
        \begin{tabitem}
    \item   Visueel inspecteren (1x per jaar)
    \item   Doorlatendheid meten (1x per 3 jaar)
        \end{tabitem}
        Onderhoud:
        \begin{tabitem}
    \item   Vegen (1-6x per jaar)
    \item   Diepreiniging (1x per 1-7 jaar) 
    \item   Aanvullen voegspit na reiniging (1x per 1-7 jaar)
    \item   Onkruidbestrijding (4-8x per jaar)
        \end{tabitem}           & €3,55 per m2      \\ 
    \midrule
\textbf{Benedengronds}
    &                           &                   \\  
    \midrule
Riolering vergroten
    &   x                       & nvt               \\
    \addlinespace[9pt]
Infiltratiebuizen
    &   Doorspuiten (1x per 3-5 jaar)   
                                & €0,05 per m       \\ 
    \addlinespace[9pt]
Infiltratiekelders  
    &   Reiniging (1x per 5 jaar)
                                & €400,00 per 100 m3    \\ 
    \addlinespace[9pt]
Infiltratiekratten
    &   \begin{tabitem}
    \item   Inspectie (1x per jaar)
    \item   Leegzuigen en onderhouden (1x per 2 jaar)
        \end{tabitem}           &   €4,40 per m2    \\ 
    \addlinespace[9pt]
Bergbezinkbassin
    &   Spoelpompen reinigen bergings
        \begin{tabitem}
    \item   kelder automatisch (getal ontbreekt)
        \end{tabitem}           &   nvt             \\
    \bottomrule
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

After two compilation the result of above MWE is:

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)